# Apache Commons CSV doesn't ignore missing column

Tags: java, csv, apache-commons-csv

Using Apache Commons CSV for parsing, but doesn't ignore missing column and throws exception.

with this sample data:

```
name age
Ali 35
John 25
Vahid 75
```

Below code `record.get(DataColumns.surname)` throws `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Mapping for surname not found, expected one of [name, surname, age]`. I need it returns null, optional or default value. Is there any option? I know it is possible with `record.toMap().get(DataColumns.surname.name())` but its performance will not be good:

```java
...
enum DataColumns { name, surname, age }
...
Reader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));

try (CSVParser records = CSVFormat.TDF
                .withDelimiter(' ')
                .withIgnoreSurroundingSpaces()
                .withAllowDuplicateHeaderNames(false)
                .withIgnoreHeaderCase()
                .withTrim()
                .withHeader(DataColumns.class)
                .withFirstRecordAsHeader()
                .withSkipHeaderRecord()
                .withAllowMissingColumnNames(false)
                .withIgnoreEmptyLines()
                .parse(in)) {

   for (CSVRecord record : records) {
       String name = record.get(DataColumns.name);
       String surname = record.get(DataColumns.surname);
       Short age = Short.valueOf(record.get(DataColumns.age)); 
   }
}

...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try using `record.isMapped(columnName)` to check if the column exists, recording into a variable so you don't have to check again every line.

Another option would be to use `records.getHeaderNames()` and store it into a variable once, before the loop, maybe even using a `Set<String>` for an extra kick of existance checking performance: `Set<String> headerNames = new HashSet<>(records.getHeaderNames())`.

Then, you can use the resulting variable inside the loop by calling `headerNames.contains(columnName)` to check whether the column exists or not.

Plese, see: https://javadoc.io/doc/org.apache.commons/commons-csv/latest/org/apache/commons/csv/CSVRecord.html

Comment: This is ok, but for more columns maybe it will decrease performance

Comment: One workaround would be to store its return value into a variable on the first record

Comment: Check only one time?

Comment: Exactly; you may get missing cells between one row or the other, but the column names will stay the same

Answer (score 0):

There is method: record.get(String) while you gave enum instead.

Try record.get(DataColumns.name.name())

Comment: Please try to explain your answer.

Comment: They are same thing, overload method ```String get(Enum<?> e)``` calls  ```String get(String name)```